# JavaScript: windoiw.location.href

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Chrome Exntesion and I'm wondering if I can have a predefined vaule to mathc the URL *window.location.href*

Currently my code looks like this;

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  if(window.location.href.indexOf("google") > -1) {
  alert("This website is google");
} else {
  alert("This website is not google");
}
```

However, it display it  as not being google. Now I know that *-1* if removed it always come up saying the website is google however, I'm not sure how to get round that.

Thanks,

Comment: _"However, it display it as not being google"_ - well then how about you first of all verify what it _actually_ contains?

Comment: @CBroe, Sorry for that. If the extension is tested on Google main page, the alert pops up with "This website is not google"

Comment: What does it show if you put alert(window.location.href) in both the alerts? I think that is what @CBroe is getting at.

Comment: fist of all, a chrome extension runs in it's own container (for the lack of a better term). This means that `window` is NOT the current open tab. If you are searching for a specific tab you need to use https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query

Comment: Not what I asked. _Check_ what `window.location.href` contains (f.e. by alerting it), as a start to recognizing where the problem actually lies.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get a list of tabs that contains "google" in their url

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, (tabs) => {
    var googleTabs = tabs.filter(tab => tab.url.indexOf("google") > -1);
    // do logic on googleTabs which is of type Tab[]. link:
    // https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab
  });
```

if you are just looking for the current tab you can use: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getCurrent